# How to calculate mean for cells matching criterion in Pandas?

Tags: python

Here's an example data frame:

```
index  location     value
  1    New York      2.0
  2    Los Angeles   1.5
  3    Chicago       -1.3
  4    New York      2.1
```

Now, I need to calculate mean for the values corresponding to New York.
How to calculate this mean in Python dataframes?

Comment: the location and values are in tabular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is a Pandas data frame named `df`.

```
df[df.location == 'New York'].value.mean()
```

Inside the brackets, we restrict the data frame to only include rows about New York. Then we specify the `value` column and take its mean, which is built into Pandas data frames.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a pandas dataframe. Then you can do like this way

```
df.set_index('location').loc['New York'].apply(np.mean)
```

Here, we set the location as index then extract only location=new york.